# Ruby On Rails image_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path

link_to(image_tag("icons/#{icon_name}.png"),url_or_object,options) I was trying use it like that but when I enter the project I'm seeing it like this http://prntscr.com/329yzz I can't see the image please help me,I am beginner in Ruby too
Please Help me

Comment: Do you have an image `show.png` under `assets/icons`? Are you using link_to in a view?

Comment: Yes I have show.png under assets/icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting raw html output.

Use `html_safe` as shown below:

**EDIT**
As per OP's comments, `html_safe` was required in `project_title_links` method to convert the link returned from `link_to_icon` into an HTML safe string(DOM ready):

```
def link_to_icon(icon_name, url_or_object,options={})     
  link_to(image_tag("icons/#{icon_name}.png", ),url_or_object,options)    
end 

def project_title_links(project) 
  content_tag :h1 do [project.title, link_to_icon('show',project) ].join(' ').html_safe end     
end
```

Comment: it isn't work but when I put ? end of html_safe like html_safe? its return true

Comment: Ok its worked 
def project_title_links(project)
    content_tag :h1 do
    [project.title,
     link_to_icon('show',project)
    ].join(' ').html_safe
    end

Answer (score 0):

`link_to` takes an optional block, if you need anything more complicated than text:

```
link_to url_or_object, options do
  image_tag("icons/#{icon_name}.png")
end
```

Since those method is being used within the views, `link_to` is using `capture` to evaluate the block. Hence it can be used like:

```
<%= link_to url_or_object, options do %>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <label>Some text</label>
    <%= image_tag("icons/#{icon_name}.png") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Actually it is helper method so I used it like 
def link_to_icon(icon_name, url_or_object,options={})
    link_to(image_tag("icons/#{icon_name}.png", ),url_or_object,options)
  end

Comment: undefined local variable or method `url_or_object' for ApplicationHelper:Module